# Virtual Env activate_this.py permission denied

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, wsgi

When running the website I get code 500, ant eh output in the apache files at the bottom.

I have changed permissions to have the appache user own the files, and even recursivly chmod 777 all files located in the virtualenv environment.

I can't make any sense of it. I've found a few points of documenation and already attempted what they have done. No success with changing permissions.

**Directory showing apache owns the file**:

```
[user@host bin]$ pwd
/Envs/AppSiteEnv/bin
[user@bhost bin]$ ls -l
total 60
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users 2202 Dec 31 15:50 activate
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users 1258 Dec 31 15:50 activate.csh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users 2471 Dec 31 15:50 activate.fish
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users 1129 Dec 31 15:50 activate_this.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  282 Dec 31 15:51 django-admin
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  141 Dec 31 15:51 django-admin.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  310 Dec 31 15:51 django-admin.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  249 Dec 31 15:50 easy_install
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  249 Dec 31 15:50 easy_install-2.7
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  221 Dec 31 15:50 pip
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  221 Dec 31 15:50 pip2
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users  221 Dec 31 15:50 pip2.7
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users 9832 Dec 31 15:50 python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users    6 Dec 31 15:50 python2 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache domain users    6 Dec 31 15:50 python2.7 -> python
(AppSiteEnv)[user@host bin]$
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/Envs/AppSiteEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

path = '/var/www/Appsite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Appsite.settings")

activate_env=os.path.expanduser('/Envs/AppSiteEnv/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Apache Logs:**

```
[error] [client 10.x.x.x] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error] [client 10.x.x.x]   File "/var/www/Appsite/Appsite/wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
[error] [client 10.x.x.x]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
[Wed Dec 31 16:02:09 2014] [error] [client 10.x.x.x] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Envs/AppSiteEnv/bin/activate_this.py'
```

Comment: Will this help? [Basic Configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration)

Comment: The use of uppercase suggests Mac vs Linux, but could you confirm (as at least RHEL 7 and similar with SELinux on can cause errors like this)

Comment: @Foon This is on RHEL 6.6. So do I need to just change the file names to all lowercase? I have beend developing in a Cent 6.6 box and didn't run into issues while using this the uppers...

Comment: @BilliAm no... i was just making an incorrect assumption; last check before I either drop my hypothesis or write an answer: what does running sestatus return (e.g. it should either return enforcing, permissivie, or disabled)

Comment: I disabled selinux and the error left. So obviously it has to be selinux?